# Do analytic function and power series agree whenever the power series converges?

Tags: power-series, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which is analytic at $x=0$.
Then
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$.
Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.
Then obviously $R>0$.
My question is: Is it possible that there is a point $p\in(-R,R)$ such that
$$f(p)\neq\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_np^n \ ?$$

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy Really. Why is that?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is analytic at $0$ and nothing else?

Comment: Analytic means equal to its power series

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Actually the answer is Yes. (See my answer below.) Is the answer No if $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x\quad&\mbox{if}\ \ |x|<\pi,\\ 0\quad&\mbox{if}\ \ |x|\geq\pi.\end{cases}$$
Then
$$f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$
in a neighborhood of $x=0$, but
$$f(3\pi/2)=0\neq-1=(3\pi/2)-\frac{(3\pi/2)^3}{3!}+\frac{(3\pi/2)^5}{5!}-\cdots.$$

Comment: Please clarify your definition of f.  What if x lies between 1 and $\pi$?

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Oops, sorry, it was a typo. 1 should have been $\pi$. I corrected it now.